Error while converting LAtex to SVG - Using the TexText plugin in Inkscape
I am encountering the following error when trying to use the TexText editor in Inkscape

Here is also the log-file text for it:
{2024-05-17 18:25:33,201+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (5104) started by pythonw in directory C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7i5agx5etextext_ with command line: C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe tmp.tex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error
2024-05-17 18:25:33,202+0200 INFO  pdflatex - running on Windows 10.0.22631
2024-05-17 18:25:33,205+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this is MiKTeX-PDFTEX 4.19.0 (1.40.26) (MiKTeX 24.4)
2024-05-17 18:25:33,208+0200 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2024-05-17 18:25:33,283+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2024-05-17 18:25:33,283+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data:
2024-05-17 18:25:33,284+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp:126
2024-05-17 18:25:33,284+0200 FATAL pdflatex - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2024-05-17 18:25:33,284+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info:
2024-05-17 18:25:33,284+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2024-05-17 18:25:33,284+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 126
2024-05-17 18:25:33,285+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (5104) finishes with exit code 1
2024-05-17 18:25:33,286+0200 WARN  pdflatex.core - still open: tmp.log
2024-05-17 18:25:33,287+0200 WARN  pdflatex.core - still open: tmp.tex}
My attempts so far:
I've updated MikTeX fully, yet i still cannot use TexText. I've read that by disabling the GUI framerwork in MikTeX could provide a solution to it - yet i couldnt find the option for doing so. I've been searching already for hours for a solution and I'D appreciate it a lot if someone could help me out!
Thanks in advance,

Can you copy us the whole text your gui thing shows in Stdout?

Welcome to TeX.SX!

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.4) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-04-11>
(C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
(C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty))
(C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))

Hey, thats the entire message as it was too long for one answer!

You can edit your question and put the output in code tags by highlighting and clicking {}.
